# Where to store extensions in a Swift project

Tags: swift, swift2

For example, I want to use this extension:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func exec (str: String) -> Array<String> {
       ....
    }
}
```

Where should I save it? Should I create a new file `extensions.swift`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For global extensions such as the one above I think it would be best to put it in an `extensions.swift` file. If your extending one of your own classes I find it best to keep it in the same file as the original class so that other developers know about it.

If you have multiple extensions for a particular global class such as `String`, you could group them into a `StringExtensions.swift` file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend keeping a group in the project and then creating Files called [Class]Extension. If you store all extension in the same file as mentioned in the other answers you might end up having a lot of issues finding the extension you are looking for and you end up with a file full of different responsibilities. In a small project that might not matter but its better to force good organisation early in a project because you never know which project might grow.

Answer (score 1):

The old-way on `objective-c` was to name like:

`UIView+FrameUtils.h`

`NSMutableArray+Sort.h`

`UIColor+HEX.h`

`NSDictionary+Nil.h`

So it's clear what is extended (categorized in objective-c) and what new functional implemented. So you may use this style in `Swift` too